# Go error handling, what's the idiomatic way for making things DRY

Tags: go

Consider the following example program which is primitive stack implementation in Go:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "errors"

const MAX_SIZE = 10

var a [10]int
var top int = -1

func main() {
    printStack()
    push(1)
    printStack()
    push(23)
    printStack()
    pop()
    push(2)
    push(24)
    push(56)
    push(87)
    push(97)
    push(47)
    push(37)
    push(31)
    push(69)
    printStack()
    push(75)
    println("Top element is", getTop())
}

func push(x int) (int, error) {
    if top >= (MAX_SIZE - 1) {
        return 0, errors.New("Error: Prevented Stackoverflow. Stack full")
    }
    top += 1
    a[top] = x
    return 0, nil
}

func pop() {
    top -= 1
}

func getTop() int {
    return a[top]
}

func printStack() {
    fmt.Println(top+1, "Stack: ", a, "Top", top)
}
```

Now, I read [Error handling and Go](http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go) & it seems the above way of returning multiple values is the way to handle errors in go.

But what I don't understand is that does do gophers check of errors on every statement? Coming from other languages this concept it bit hard for me to grok.  So the question is

1. What is the idiomatic way of handling errors in above problem?
2. Is considered a bad practice if I don't check for errors? if yes, then I am supposed to check the output of `push()` everytime I call it?

Basically what I want to know if how would a experienced gopher do error handling in the above program?

Play URL: https://play.golang.org/p/_AnZLvY-28

**[Update]**
Added a real-world program where I fetch data from database & output to json. http://play.golang.org/p/dDApCYprjU

Comment: Consider reading [this](https://blog.golang.org/errors-are-values).

Comment: And this: https://medium.com/@divan/explaining-go-error-handling-44099bcd2b1f (which also links to the mentioned article)

Comment: You can always write contrived examples which make error handling look more awkward than it should. Your code is very repetitive, therefor error handling will be too. Try reading through good code examples, and write some code that is more representative of real life problems.

Comment: @JimB Point taken. Real-world example added. now how do I refactor this to be idiomatic go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the idiomatic way to produce errors is to return multiple values.  The idiomatic way to handle errors is this:

```
val, err := myFunc()
if err != nil {
    // do something with err
}

// do something with val
```

At the end of the day it's a judgement call, but it's almost always good practice to handle errors.  The code you're writing is also a bit unusual, you normally don't have 10 calls to the same function back-to-back, so the verbose error handling you'd have to do is more a result of the original code.  For instance, you could use a loop:

```
for _, num := range []int{2, 24, 56, 87, 97, 47, 37, 31, 69} {
    _, err := push(num)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

You have some other things that are more problematic than not handling the push errors though.  One minor thing is there is no reason for `push` to always return 0, why not only have it return an error, instead of an int and an error?  The bigger problem is that `pop` keeps decrementing `top`, and `getTop` just accesses `a[top]`, so you can easily get a runtime panic if `top` becomes negative from having `pop`ped too much.  You probably want some error handling or other safeguards in your `pop` and `getTop` functions.

Comment: I wanted to handle that error too but was not sure what's the right way to go about it. But now This makes more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard way of handling the errors in go-lang. There are two options that can follow after an error took place.

1.log the error and entirely quit the program

2. log the error and do some relevant task

Option one example :

```
func funcX() {
    rtnval, err := funcY()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error: ", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    //rtnval 
}
```