# Shorten repeating code with error checking

Tags: go

```
func parseData(rows []Row) ([]db.StandardImportUpsertStandardParams, error) {
    for _, row := range rows {

        startDate, err := parseTime("02/01/2006", row["Date of start of presumption of conformity (1)"])
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        restrictionStartDate, err := parseTime("02/01/2006", row["Date of start of presumption of conformity with restriction (4)"])
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        withdrawalDate, err := parseTime("02/01/2006", row["Date of withdrawal from OJ (end of presumption of conformity) (6)"])
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
```

Having this code, I see repeating stuff. Is there a way to make this more elegant/shorter? Putting this into a function would not help, because I need to check and forward error.

Comment: This is re-asked about every month or so.

Comment: @Flimzy I don't know what words to use to search for the existing questions... Sorry.

Comment: I think the linked question is a little bit different. Here I have more repetition -- same function is called and the result is put into different var each time.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/33595102/13860

Comment: If it's reasonable to operate on a map/slice, you could loop through the key/value pairs, thus having the function name only once.  For just 3 iterations, setting that up is probably more complicated/verbose than what you have now.  If you have a dozen or more iterations, it may be more readable and maintainable.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/JymqkBJrddO the approach may be useful is some cases but, in my opinion, not so much in this one... I'll still leave it here though, it may prompt a better idea from someone else.